# Sorting a column with mix numeric and text where the numeric or text is 1-3 digits long

Tags: sorting, ms-access, jquery-ui-sortable

Sorting a column with mix numeric and text where the numeric or text is 1-3 digits long

Greetings everyone!

I am New to this and I have a sorting problem on Access 2007 database. This database will identify different types of task per classification code. When I use the ascending order, the order isn’t proper since these classification code are a mixture of a numeric and text. There are over 300 codes in all. Below is a short sample of what I’m dealing with. Please note that we are continually adding new classification code in-between existing code.
The format is really terrible, it could be 1A or 1AA or 1AAA or 11A or 111A and so on… 
I would like to know how to achieve the desired sort and not the default

The Desired Sort (keeping the code in order by the numeric value and text secondary)

```
1.  1A
2.  1B
3.  2A
4.  2B
5.  3A
6.  4B
7.  11A
8.  12BC
9.  22B
10. 22C
```

The default Sort

```
1.  11A
2.  12BC
3.  1A
4.  1B
5.  22B
6.  22C
7.  2A
8.  2B
9.  3A
10. 4B
```

What is the best method to get my desired sort? and please give me a step by step how to do so, since i'm still very new to this.

Comment: Use `Val(FieldNameHere)` Sort on the result. Come back with your code and any problems.

Comment: Be aware that Val can be a bit temperamental, so `val("a1")` is 0 and `val("1a2")` is 1, in other words, it will only pick up the first few digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be something like,

```
SELECT sampTbl.IdField
FROM sampTbl
ORDER BY Val([IdField]), sampTbl.IdField;
```